# Weird three divs side by side

Tags: css, html, layout, css-tables

I'm a tables guy, but I'll need to drag and drop some divs, so I tried doing it tabeless (the right way).

This is what I want to do:
[image: Design]

The space between all elements should be 24px. My main problem is having the divs (1,2,3) occupying 100% of available space. The width: 100% its sending them beyond the main container.

This is my code so far:

html

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="topContainer">Just the top one
</div>
<div id="table">
    <div id="Line1Container">
    <div id="container1" class="container">1
    </div>
    <div id="container2" class="container">2
    </div>
    <div id="container3" class="container">3
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Line2Container">
    <div id="container4" class="container">4
    </div>
    <div id="container5" class="container">5
    </div>
    <div id="container6" class="container">6
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And my css

```
#mainContainer {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    position:fixed;
    top: 80px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:80px;
    right:80px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#topContainer {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

#table {
    display: table;
    margin: 24px;
    width: 95%;
}

#Line1Container, #Line2Container {
    display: table-row;
}

.container  {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

As you see I tried the table-cell approach, but before I have tried the float: left approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a table for separating the divs? that way with the td padding there will always be 24px between them

check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5zfEq/

added:

```
#Line1Container {
    padding:12px;
}
#inner-table {
    width: 100%;
}
#inner-table td {
    padding: 12px;
}
```

based on @Edifice fiddle .... thanks ;)

Comment: i havent used `display: table;`?

Comment: Ah I thought you'd just added something to the OP's original code. But it is clear from the question that they are trying to avoid using tables for layout.

Comment: oops! your right, sorry, got carried away in the jsfiddle realm! :s

Comment: I might use your solution if I cant do it other way. Just need to make sure that I'll be able to drag'n drop those divs between them. Shouldn't be a problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi David, your answer, although using tables, its the one that best fits my problem. I got back to project today and encounter one problem, when I add content to cells, each one starts assuming different width, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ptay/

Comment: I applied table-layout: fixed; to inner-table and overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; to container. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9P5py/)

You can't properly use `px` values with `%` values together with dynamic sizes.
You should use x% instead of 24px.
And you can use `float: left` on the "cells"

Comment: and you don't need to set `tr` elements (here LineXContainer) for the table rows, because if the cell is not fit on a row, it will just jump down to the next line.

Comment: My only problem is that designer has the 24px measure on the PDF specification. But thanks for solution.

Comment: Than you should use `px` values for the cells too.
Take a look at [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). They have a responsive grid system, that changes width if you resizing your window, but you can use exact with for your cells.